# Flutter: How to handle using StreamProvider, FireStore and using Drawer

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, android-contentprovider, flutter-provider

I have a problem in using 'StreamProvider' and having 'Provider.of' delivering the goodies. I have two interlinked issues. (1) is I can't get ProxyProvider to work (and most likely I am just misunderstanding it, and it may not be the solution). (2) The widget Drawer() (or the way I am using it) seems to block 'Provider.of'. 'StreamProvider' can't be found up the tree.

In MyApp() I initially had:

```
return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<User>.value(value: AuthService().user),
        StreamProvider<UserData>.value(
            value: DatabaseServices(uid: 'user.userUid').userData),
        StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>.value(
            value: DatabaseServices(uid: 'user.userUid').allTasks),
        StreamProvider<List<TaskDetails>>.value(
            value: DatabaseServices(uid: 'user.userUid').userTasksByImportance),
        StreamProvider<List<PropertyDetails>>.value(
            value: DatabaseServices(uid: 'UuO2DO0JUVbVD0R1JqIclI7fprF3')
                .userProperties),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: themeData,
        home: Wrapper(),
        routes: {
          SettingsForm.id: (context) => SettingsForm(),
          TaskList.id: (context) => TaskList(),
          AddTask.id: (context) => AddTask(),
          EditTask.id: (context) => EditTask(),
          PropertyList.id: (context) => PropertyList(),
          AddProperty.id: (context) => AddProperty(),
          AddUnit.id: (context) => AddUnit(),
          TestMarkdown.id: (context) => TestMarkdown(),
        },
      ),
    );
```

I tried to use ProxyProvider to supply a user.userUid from StreamProvider to the other StreamProviders below it but couldn't get anything to work.

Next in Wrapper() I tried this:

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    if (user == null) {
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
      return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          StreamProvider<UserData>.value(
              value: DatabaseServices(uid: user.userUid).userData),
          StreamProvider<List<TaskDetails>>.value(
              value: DatabaseServices(uid: user.userUid).userTasksByImportance),
          StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>.value(
              value: DatabaseServices(uid: user.userUid).allTasks),
          StreamProvider<List<PropertyDetails>>.value(
              value: DatabaseServices(uid: user.userUid).userProperties),
        ],
        child: Home(),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Now this is below MaterialApp() which I didn't think was a good idea, but I could make user.user.Uid available to the other StreamProvider(s) and all worked. Provider.of in Home() and HomePage() (called by Home()) supplied the goodies.

Now Home() has a Drawer:

```
 return Scaffold(
        drawer: buildDrawer(context),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent[50],
        appBar: appBar,
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            image: DecorationImage(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                image: AssetImage('assets/property_returns_logo_drawn.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
          ),
          child: HomePage(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  Drawer buildDrawer(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    final userData = Provider.of<UserData>(context);
    final userProperties = Provider.of<List<PropertyDetails>>(context);
    final double _minHeight = 40;
    final double _maxHeight = 40;

    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
```

and userProperties is available within the drawer itself, but any widget called from the drawer gives the error that it can't find a relevant StreamProvider for the Provider.of. If I reput the relevant StreamProvider back in MyAPP() the relevant StreamProvider can be found. But with no values from Firestore unless I fudge and for user.userUid hardcode a valid uid:. Obviously not a solution but works as far as the widgets called by Drawer is concerned.

What I am looking for is to understand how to use ProxyProvider, or if that is not the solution, how to structure my code. Maybe I can use StreamProviders (or StreamBuilders) in every widget called from Drawer but that doesn't feel right. Code is at https://github.com/sctajc/property_returns.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, ProxyProvider doesn't work as the StreamProvider, so you cannot use it the way you want.

To answer why your `Drawer` has access to `Provider.of<Foo>` while the routes opened from it haven't, is because the `routes` are defined in your `MaterialApp`.

What does this mean? It means that while `Drawer` is below `Wrapper` and thus, has access to `Provider.of<Foo>`, the other routes are technically **above** the `Wrapper` widget.

TL:DR

The solution would be just creating one `ProxyProvider` of your `DatabaseServices` like this:

```
ProxyProvider<User, DatabaseServices>(
    update: (_, user, __) => DatabaseServices(uid: user?.userUid),
),
```

And then, if you need to tap into the UserData, you just need to do:

```
Provider.of<DatabaseServices>(context).userData
```

This way you avoid creating 4 instances of the same object (DatabaseServices) and at the same time, you solve your problem. However, the logic of your app will need to change a bit to make it work, I am sure it won't be a problem.

I hope this can help you and you can keep on developing your app!

Comment: Thanks Francisco. That certainly helped me understand the issue and I have made code changes as you suggested. with something like

Comment: Provider.of<DatabaseServices>(context).userProperties;' I can print() out that there is an instance. What I am now struggling now with is accessing the data within userProperties. This I would have thought would be similar approach to before ('userProperty.propertyName' or 'userProperty[i].userName' (if in a List)) but any hints on what to try?

Comment: You could use some StreamBuilders to read the data for example. I understand that this might be a little more work but the other option would be creating your own StreamProxyProvider... I understand that it is more work that what you were doing up until now but there aren't many other options!

Comment: Thanks Francisco. Now I understand the issues I can move forward